# identifying rows in data frame that exhibit patterns

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching, match

Below I have code with 3 columns: a group field, a open/close field for the store, and the rolling sum of 3 month opens for the store.  I also have the desired solution output.

My dataset can be thought of as an employees availability.   You can assume each row to be a different time period (hour, day,month, year, whatever).   In the open/closed column I have whether or not the employee was present.  The 3month rolling column is a sum of the previous rows.

What I want to identify is the non-zero values in this rolling sum column **following** a gap of at *least* 3 zero rows *for that particular group*.  While not present in this dataset, you can assume that there might be more than one 'gap' of zeros present.

```
 structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), X0_closed_1_open =      c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3month_roll_open = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), desired_solution = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class ="factor")), .Names = c("Group", "X0_closed_1_open", "X3month_roll_open", "desired_solution"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -26L))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
res <- unsplit(
         lapply(split(df1, df1$Group), function(x) {
          rl <- with(x,rle(X3month_roll_open==0))
          indx <- cumsum(c(0,diff(inverse.rle(within.list(rl, 
                    values[values] <- lengths[values]>=3)))<0))
          x$Flag <- indx!=0 & x[,3]!=0
          x}),
        df1$Group)
```

**NOTE:** Instead of 'yes/no', it may be better to have 'TRUE/FALSE' for easing subsetting.

```
 identical(c('no', 'yes')[res$Flag+1L], as.character(res$desired_solution))
 #[1] TRUE
```